# cURL retrieve only header without doing HEAD

Tags: php, curl

So I am trying to retrieve only headers using cURL with the following:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

The problem is that while trying to get headers of large file the script uses all the memory. I would like to avoid getting also the body and I have tried to use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

The problem is that this issues a HEAD request instead of GET. And some website retrun an error when you request with HEAD.

Is there any way with curl to retrieve only header without doing HEAD request?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` as that's the option that makes it keep the entire response in memory.

Then, two options:

A) use a write callback and make that abort the transfer as soon as the first byte of the body is returned. There's a [write callback example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#98491) in the PHP.net docs.

B) use `CURLOPT_RANGE` and ask for only the first byte to be retrieved, `0-0`. This avoids the write callback but has the downside that not all HTTP servers and URLs will acknowledge it.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to use cURL, you could use `get_headers()`. By default get_headers uses a GET request to fetch the headers. And you could also modify that request by using `stream_context_set_default()`

```
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com');
```

More Info: [PHP: get_headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Comment: yes that's an option but something get_headers isn't reliable and is slower